# Ошибка RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MatchPage has been deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import qdarkstyle
from match_page import MatchPage
from bernulli_page import BernulliPage
from poisson_page import PoissonPage
from season_page import SeasonPage
from tournament_page import TournamentPage

class UI_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUI(self, MainWindow, WIDTH, HEIGHT):
        self.DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1680
        self.DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 1010 - 25
        self.HEIGHT = HEIGHT  # чтобы за панель задач не уезжало окно
        self.WIDTH = WIDTH
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

    self.set_pages()

    app_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    app_icon.addFile('icons/ball-16.png', QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
    app_icon.addFile('icons/ball-24.png', QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
    app_icon.addFile('icons/ball-32.png', QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Football Analytics")
    self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
    # self.scroll_area.setObjectName('scroll_area')
    # self.scroll_area.setStyleSheet('#scroll_area{border:none}')
    self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
    self.scroll_area.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
        200, 30, self.WIDTH - 220, self.HEIGHT - 70))

    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.match_page)

    self.set_menu()
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

def set_pages(self):
    """
    создание страниц приложения и установка их размеров
    """
    self.match_page = MatchPage()
    self.season_page = SeasonPage()
    self.bernulli_page = BernulliPage()
    self.poisson_page = PoissonPage()
    self.tournament_page = TournamentPage()
    pages = (self.match_page, self.season_page, self.bernulli_page,
             self.poisson_page, self.tournament_page)
    for page in pages:
        page.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
            0, 0, self.DEFAULT_WIDTH - 250, self.DEFAULT_HEIGHT - 80))

def set_menu(self):
    """
    добавление меню в прилржение
    """
    self.menu = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.menu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 150, self.HEIGHT - 50))
    self.match_item = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.menu)
    self.match_item.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 130, 20))
    self.match_item.setText("Матч")

    self.season_item = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.menu)
    self.season_item.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 130, 20))
    self.season_item.setText("Сезон")


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """
    класс окна приложения, задает интерфейс и перехватывает события
    """
    def __init__(self, WIDTH, HEIGHT):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1680
        self.DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 1010 - 25
        self.HEIGHT = HEIGHT - 25  # чтобы за панель задач не уезжало окно
        self.WIDTH = WIDTH
        self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUI(self, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.ui.match_item.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.scroll_area.setWidget(self.ui.match_page))
        self.ui.season_item.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.scroll_area.setWidget(self.ui.season_page))
        # self.setMinimumSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        # self.setWindowFlags(
        #     QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint |
        #     QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
        #     QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)  # убрал на время тестов размера

def closeEvent(self, event):
    """
    перехват события закрытия окна, вывод окна с вопросом при
    возникновении события
    :param event: - событие
    """
    msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    msg.setWindowTitle("Выход")
    msg_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    msg_icon.addFile('icons/ball-16.png', QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
    msg.setWindowIcon(msg_icon)
    msg.setText("Вы действительно хотите выйти?")
    button_yes = msg.addButton("Да", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
    msg.addButton("Нет", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
    msg.setDefaultButton(button_yes)
    msg.exec_()
    if msg.clickedButton() != button_yes:
        event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
    # print(screen.width(), screen.height())
    MainWindow = MyWindow(screen.width(), screen.height())
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyside2())
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background: #121e29")
    MainWindow.showMaximized()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Такая ошибка вылетает при переключении кнопок в меню. Что делать? Чего не хватает?
Отступы немного съехали

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17914960

Comment: Что делать? - Опубликовать минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @S.Nick в посте он и есть

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна помощь, опубликуйте пример, который демонстрирует проблему. Где ваши модули `match_page.py`, `bernulli_page.py` и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно использовать `QStackedWidget` и переключать страницы с помощью него, а не менять виджеты в `scroll_area` с помощью `setWidget()`